# Is Interface inheritance a bad practice?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I was wondering if the following code shows a bad practice (about interface inheritance):

```
public interface IFoo : IDisposable
{
    void Test();
}

public class TestImpl : IFoo
{
    public void Test()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // disposing my dependencies
    }
}

public class FooFactory
{
    public IFoo CreateFoo()
    {
        return new TestImpl();
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public void Main()
    {
        FooFactory factory = new FooFactory();
        using(IFoo foo = factory.CreateFoo())
        {
            // do stuff then auto-dispose
            foo.Test();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I wanted two things:
1. Use the C#'s using statement so I can dispose my concrete object's dependencies elegantly (no need to cast anything to IDisposable).
2. Use a factory method to create a concrete object, so I can work only with the interfaces.

Separated, both are known good practices, but together? I didn't find anything saying it's wrong here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229022.aspx (MSDN - Interface Design), but I think it doesn't sound good...

I would appreciate any comment about this. If it's a bad practice, what kind of issues I would run into using this approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Almost every .NET object that is disposable does basically this.

Comment: Please see [my update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997648/is-interface-inheritance-a-bad-practice/6997732#6997732), you can use Google to find such interfaces in .NET Framework itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the wild, there is no such thing as a definitely good or bad practice, each has its upsides and downsides.
A practice becomes good or bad only when it is **applied to a concrete problem** (read: not `IFoo`).

```
public bool IsGood<TContext>(IPractice practice)
    where TContext : RealWorldApplication, new();
```

So, instead of trying to find guidance on MSDN, ask yourself the following question:

> **Does this solve the problem *and* make the code simpler to read?**

If the answer is *yes*, go with it.

Personally, I like the approach. If the contract for `IFoo` **requires** proper disposal (think: `IGraphicalObject`, `IResource`, `IConnection`), it's a very good design decision to make this explicit.

Don't be trapped by dogma: programming with interfaces makes you less dependent on concrete implementations, but programming **only** with interfaces can be a nightmare. Be reasonable, that's it.

#### Update

You can use Google to find all interfaces that inherit from `IDisposable` in .NET Framework itself:

> [`intitle:interface "inherits idisposable" site:msdn.microsoft.com`](http://www.google.com/search?q=intitle:interface%20%22inherits%20idisposable%22%20site:msdn.microsoft.com)

As I said above, this is normally done for entities that are *known* to consume resources, such as database connections, unmanaged object wrappers, graphical objects, et cetera.

Imposing implementing `Dispose()` on a class that has **nothing to dispose of** would be a bad idea.
In this case it's better to leave it optional and check for `IDisposable` support, as [suggested by Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997648/is-interface-inheritance-a-bad-practice/6997823#6997823).

Comment: There are plenty of definitely bad practices in the wild.

Comment: Yep, but you can't say that something *is* a bad practice for 100% without seeing the *actual application of it*. *Practice* is a very slippery word; there *are* some cases when something generally considered a bad practice *is* the best way to do something in a concrete situation. I'm only saying, **think for yourself** (of course this only works when you trust your thinking—if I'm not sure, I would **describe my exact situation** and seek advice on StackOverflow but not ask about “practices”).

Comment: @Henk: I made an edit to highlight this, maybe you'd like to check it out.

Comment: Interfaces should inherit IDisposable if it is possible that an object implementing the interface may need to know when someone is done with it, especially if the last entity using it may not know its specific type.  Even if 99.9% of implementations of an interface won't care, leaving omitting IDisposable may cause problems for the last few.  A nice example of this is IEnumerator<T>.  Most enumerators don't care when they're no longer needed, but a few types do.  If IEnumerator<T> didn't implement IDisposable, code which uses enumerators would have to...

Comment: ...either try casting the enumerator to IDisposable and call Dispose if the cast succeeds, or else skip disposal and hope that doesn't cause trouble like leaving a file open or something.  It's generally faster to have IEnumerator<T> inherit IDisposable and have consumers dispose unconditionally, than it would be to check whether disposal was necessary and only call it if so.

Answer (score 10):

This is perfectly valid. That's exactly what interfaces are for. They define contracts. A contract can be built using several sub contracts.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is correct. Your factory hides what class is actually instantiated so `IFoo` have to inherit `IDisposable` for the client to be able to call `Dispose()`. With this class the client can - and should - be totally unaware of the actual class instantiated. All relevant information should be carried by the interface - including the need for disposal.

Answer (score 2):

Technically everything is fine with this solution.

From a semantic point of view you could argue that the need of `IDisposable` is an implementation detail and has nothing to do with the actual contract of your class.

What you can do is cast the object to `IDisposable` and call `Dispose()` only, if it implements `IDisposable`:

```
var disposable = foo as IDisposable;

if (disposable != null)
    disposable.Dispose();
```

But in this case I would go with interface inheritance as you suggested it. It isn't the cleanest aproach, but does the job for you perfectly and needs less code.